How to unpause Airflow DAG without triggering
I created a dag factory.
I switch the dags to the unpause state and they immediately start working, despite the set schedule interval value. Tried to override DagModel by specifying is_active=False. Nothing helped...
I tried different methods of influence: API, Sessions, etc.
I need to automatically switch dags to unpause so that they work strictly according to schedule and do not start immediately

Have you made sure your start_date is set correctly in your DAG? If it's in the past, Airflow will try to run all missed DAG runs from that time up until the present (if catchup=False, it will run the most recent interval only). This can cause the DAG to trigger immediately upon unpausing.
If you want the DAG to run from a specific future time, set start_date to that point & it will prevent it from running immediately.
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 1, 1), # Future date here
}

dag = DAG(
    'my_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    catchup=False  # Disable backfilling
)


I'd suggest to set the start date to future date to start with, you can also use "is_paused_upon_creation" parameter in the ref [1]
[1] https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html#airflow.models.dag.DAG
